# Batch file that calls a vsim command

Tags: batch-file, modelsim

I have a batch file that calls vsim -c -do test.tcl, after it's done I want to execute some more code. The problem is that in the command line it stays in the vsim command and doesn't return to execute the next instructions in the batch file.

Like so:

vsim -c -do test.tcl  <---- stuck here

if exist test1 del test1 <--- cant execute this

Comment: Please include more of your code. It is likely that you need to utilize the `call` or `start` commands, when calling `vsim`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell `vsim` to quit by putting the `quit` command at the end of test.tcl (assuming it is a simple straight line script). Otherwise it stays in interactive mode waiting for more commands.

The `-do` option has two variants. One takes a script file name as a parameter. The other takes a string of Tcl commands. If you ever want to run simulations manually in command line mode you can use the option `-do "run -all; quit"` to get the same effect without a script.

Answer (score 1):

```
vsim -c -do "do test.tcl; quit -f"
```

or

```
vsim -batch -do "do test.tcl; quit -f"
```

Comment: A related question: test.tcl generates coverage reports to a file when sourced through the Transcript window of Modelsim. But when I use the command `vsim -c -keepstdout -do "do test.tcl"`, it doesn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that everyone is familiar with `vsim`. Please let me assure you, you are working under a grave misapprehesion.

What do you mean by "stays in the vsim command"? Does the batch terminate or not?

If vsim is a batch file, then the solution may be in what you've posted.

```
vsim -c -do test.tcl
```

should be

```
call vsim -c -do test.tcl
```

which will execute `vsim` and continue when `vsim` is finished.